# nl2br() deletes content between <br />

Tags: php, sql-server, newline

i'm getting a string from an mssql -database to my .php-page.

For good look, I want to replace the newlines with `<br />`
so I tried the following (one at a time):

```
echo nl2br($data);
echo str_replace(chr(10), "<br />",str_replace(chr(13), "<br />", $data))
echo str_replace("\n", "<br />",str_replace("\r", "<br />", $data))
```

The HTML-source code looks all right:

```
blablalba<br />sdsddsfdfs<br />fds<br />dfsdfs<br />fdsdsf<br />:_k,ölmjlö<br />öä.löälöä#<br />
```

But the result on the HTML is empty, and Chrome developer-tools is displaying following:

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

What am I missing?

echo $data is giving me the right result but without `<br />`'s

```
blablalba sdsddsfdfs fds dfsdfs fdsdsf :_k,ölmjlö öä.löälöä#
```

Regards

Comment: `str_replace` isn't multibyte safe, so you can't use it with a multibyte encoded string.

Comment: `"\n"` is equal to `chr(10)` and `"\r"` is equal to `chr(13)` ... and nl2br() replaces both of them. Check you `$data` contains data.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it was just a try, i am desperate :o .$data contains data as i can see in the HTML-source

Comment: What does `echo $data` give you? WHen chrome developer tools tell you `<br><br><br>`, then where exactly did you take the other HTML source code from?

Comment: Other thing, trying to replace directly newlines with `<br>` in an html source is dangerous since the newlines characters can be inside the tags.

Comment: @Alexander by pressing CTRL + U I get the RAW source-code in chrome

Comment: So NOW you are telling us that this has NOTHING to do with PHP, because both the raw HTML and the "auto-corrected" HTML are client-side. First, put all your client-side HTML into an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and sort out all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wordwrap...

> Wrap a string into new lines when it reaches a specific length:

```
<?php
$str = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic";

echo wordwrap($str,15,"<br>\n");
```

?>

> Result:

```
An example of a
long word is:
Supercalifragulistic
```

Comment: same behavior, table-cell keeps beeing empty